# Send space in route mvc

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have to implement search with MVC3, where user can search any word or words, now if i write only a sigle word its work fine and my route will be like
**/search/toy**
and toy is recognise by my controller method.

But if i want to search something with space like 'kid toy' then route have a space and in my controller method it doesn't recognise it as a word and throw error like 
**/search/kids%20toy**

Has anyone implement such thing in his project plz help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an action called "Toy".

```
// maps to /search/
public class Search : Controller
{
    // maps to /search/toy
    public ActionResult Toy()
    {
    }
}
```

If you haven't modified the default routes at all, you need to use {controller}/{action}/{id}.
(Of course you'll have to look into routing if you want to do different kind of routes. Ask google for ASP.NET MVC routing)

Here's the quickest way:

```
// maps to /search
public class Search : Controller
{
    // maps to /search/for/{id}
    public ActionResult For(string id)
    {
        // search for id 
    }
}
```

Which could be used as /search/for/kids%20toy.

Or you can use querystring for parameters named something else than id.

```
// maps to /search
public class Search : Controller
{
    // maps to /search/ by default, check route config
    public ActionResult Index(string query)
    {
        // search for query
    }
}
```

To be able to use {controller}/{action}/{query} or {controller}/{query} you'll have to create a route, but you can address that one by 
/search/?query=kids%20toy